# API Gateway ocelot with authorization Dotnet6

Tags: .net, .net-core, ocelot

i want to pass token between micro service using Ocelot
just like this:

[image]

this code dont work in other microservice

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, Roles = "Admin")]

public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
{
```